# How to get the HTML content from HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I have managed to setup a filter for the servlet on tomcat, but the HttpServletResponse only has functions to get the response headers, not the actual HTML response itself. Some reading told me that I have to make a wrapper class but I don't know how to go about this. After a lot of head wracking, I decided to post this on stackoverflow.

How can I retrieve the HTML content from the HttpServletResponse? I need to save it as a text file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) interface, especially methods getWriter and getOutputStream and then provide that class to the doFilter method. At the end you will dump contents of the buffer to the file.

Check a bit similar problem here [response wrapper to convert all output to uppercase](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Filterthatusesaresponsewrappertoconvertalloutputtouppercase.htm)